# mysql #1045 - Access denied in online server for GRANT SUPER

Tags: mysql, super, sql-grant

I have a online server with phpmyadmin. i want to use events, but i can't.

[image: that's my problem]

Comment: by default the 'root' account should already have `all` privileges, which includes `super`. it'd be odd for root to be under-privileged, unless it was done for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same problem and I just fixed it. Try granting root permissions explicitly for the database you are using.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${database}.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${pass}';
```

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON u865570182_bbdd.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'serverpass' 
this give me a same error   #1044 - Access denied for user 'u865570182_admin'@'localhost' to database 'u865570182_bbdd'